# Dúvida: resposta aleatória

Tags: python-3.x

Programa que faz uma pergunta e responde aleatório, e se a resposta não ajudar ele repeti, na hora do sim ele vai, mas quando coloca não ele 'buga'

```
import random
from time import sleep
pergunta = str(input('Oque você deseja saber?'))
print('PENSANDO...')
for contagem in range (0,3):
    sleep(1)
respostas = ['Não sei', 'Talvez', 'Não sei oque responder', 'Você sabe a resposta é só pensar mais um pouco', 'nao estou no nivel dessa pergunta', 'OK', 'Sim', 'Não ', 'Banana', 'Massa',]
print(random.choice(respostas))
aprovaçao = str(input('Essa resposta te ajudou?'))

if aprovaçao == 'sim':
    pritn('Volte sempre')

elif aprovaçao == 'nao':
    print('PENSANDO...')
    for contagem in range(0, 3):
        sleep(1)
    print(random.choice(respostas))
aprovaçao1 = str(input('Essa resposta te ajudou?'))
if aprovaçao1 == 'sim':
    pritn('Volte sempre')

elif aprovaçao1 == 'nao':
    print('PENSANDO...')
    for contagem in range(0, 3):
        sleep(1)
    print(random.choice(respostas))
aprovaçao3 = str(input('Essa resposta te ajudou?'))
if aprovaçao3 == 'sim':
    pritn('Volte sempre')

elif aprovaçao3 == 'nao':
    print('PENSANDO...')
    for contagem in range(0, 3):
        sleep(1)
    print(random.choice(respostas))
```

Comment: Detalhe: `input` retorna uma string, então `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário, faça apenas `input(...)`. E se quer pausar por 3 segundos, não precisa do `for`, faça apenas `sleep(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Seu programa estava bugando pois você estava perguntando diversas vezes, usando vários ifs ao invés de um laço de repetição.

**Olhe como o programa deveria se comportar:**

```
import random
from time import sleep
pergunta = str(input('Oque você deseja saber? '))
respostas = ['Não sei', 'Talvez', 'Não sei oque responder', 'Você sabe a resposta é só pensar mais um pouco', 'nao estou no nivel dessa pergunta', 'OK', 'Sim', 'Não ', 'Banana',     'Massa',]
while pergunta != 'sim': # este será um loop enquanto a resposta for diferente de "sim"
  print('PENSANDO...') # a cada resposta, ele irá printar "PENSANDO..."
  sleep(3) # espero 3 segundos
  print(random.choice(respostas)) # printa uma possível resposta
  pergunta = str(input('Esta resposta responde sua pergunta? ')) # pergunta se o usuário está satisfeito com a resposta, se sim o programa acaba
print('Volte sempre!')
```